# How to submit matrix and category fields in frontend

Tags: twig, craftcms

So i have an entry to submit games.
The games entry has a lot of different fields, and one of the fields is:

- a field with fieldType "category" linked to a category
- a field with fieldType "matrix" called materialList that looks like this:

[image: how my field called "materialList" looks like]

*The "MaterialName" has fieldType categories and is linked to a category*

---

So now I am trying to submit a form in my frontend.
So far I managed to correctly save regular text fields, but I failed to correctly save something as a matrix, and I failed to properly save a category that is correctly linked.

I already found an example on https://craftcms.com/knowledge-base/entry-form but this only shows me the regular text fields.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<form method="post" accept-charset="UTF-8">
        {{ csrfInput() }}
        {{ actionInput('entries/save-entry') }}
        {{ redirectInput('spelen/{slug}') }}
        {{ hiddenInput('sectionId', '1') }}
        {{ hiddenInput('enabled', '1') }}

        <label for="title">Title</label>
        {{ input('text', 'title', entry.title, {
            id: 'title',
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('title')) }}

        <label for="youngestAge">Minimum leeftijd</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'youngestAge',
            type: 'number',
            name: 'fields[youngestAge]',
            text: entry.youngestAge,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('youngestAge')) }}

        <label for="oldestAge">Maximum leeftijd</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'oldestAge',
            type: 'number',
            name: 'fields[oldestAge]',
            text: entry.oldestAge,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('oldestAge')) }}

        <label for="leastAmountOfPlayers">Minimum aantal spelers</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'leastAmountOfPlayers',
            type: 'number',
            name: 'fields[leastAmountOfPlayers]',
            text: entry.leastAmountOfPlayers,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('leastAmountOfPlayers')) }}

        <label for="mostAmountOfPlayers">Maximum aantal spelers</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'mostAmountOfPlayers',
            type: 'number',
            name: 'fields[mostAmountOfPlayers]',
            text: entry.mostAmountOfPlayers,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('mostAmountOfPlayers')) }}

        <label for="groups">Aantal groepen</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'groups',
            type: 'number',
            name: 'fields[groups]',
            text: entry.groups,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('groups')) }}

        <label for="gametime">Speelduur</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'gametime',
            type: 'time',
            name: 'fields[gametime]',
            text: entry.gametime,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('gametime')) }}


        <label for="intro">Intro</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'intro',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'fields[intro]',
            text: entry.intro,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('intro')) }}

        <label for="purpose">Doel van het spel</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'purpose',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'fields[purpose]',
            text: entry.purpose,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('purpose')) }}

        <label for="explenation">Speluitleg</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'explenation',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'fields[explenation]',
            text: entry.explenation,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('explenation')) }}

        <label for="gameType">Spel type</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'gameType',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'fields[gameType]',
            value: 6,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('gameType')) }}

        <label for="materialItem">Material</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'gameType',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'fields[materialItem]',
            value: entry.materialItem,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('materialItem')) }}

        <label for="isPublic">Publiek</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'isPublic',
            type: 'checkbox',
            name: 'fields[isPublic]',
            text: false,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('isPublic')) }}


        <label for="body">Body</label>
        {{ tag('textarea', {
            id: 'body',
            name: 'fields[body]',
            text: 'test bericht',
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('body')) }}

        <button type="submit">Publish</button>
    </form>
```

So these are the 2 I need help with:
The first input needs to properly save linked categories
The second one needs to properly save a matrix

```
        <label for="gameType">Spel type</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'gameType',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'fields[gameType]',
            value: 6,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('gameType')) }}

        <label for="materialItem">Material</label>
        {{ tag('input', {
            id: 'gameType',
            type: 'text',
            name: 'fields[materialItem]',
            value: entry.materialItem,
        }) }}
        {{ _self.errorList(entry.getErrors('materialItem')) }}
```

Answer (score 0):

So I found out how to save a category, but I'm still stuck on the matrix part.

This is the code for the category:

```
{# Include a hidden input first so Craft knows to update the existing value
   if no checkboxes are checked. #}
{{ hiddenInput('fields[myFieldHandle]', '') }}

{# Get all of the possible category options #}
{% set possibleCategories = craft.categories()
  .group('food')
  .all() %}

{# Get the currently related category IDs #}
{% set relatedCategoryIds = entry is defined
  ? entry.myFieldHandle.ids()
  : [] %}

<ul>
  {% nav possibleCategory in possibleCategories %}
    <li>
      <label>
        {{ input(
          'checkbox',
          'fields[myFieldHandle][]',
          possibleCategory.id,
          { checked: possibleCategory.id in relatedCategoryIds }
        ) }}
        {{ possibleCategory.title }}
      </label>
      {% ifchildren %}
        <ul>
          {% children %}
        </ul>
      {% endifchildren %}
    </li>
  {% endnav %}
</ul>
```